# What is the difference between httpunit 1.7.2 and the kohsuke patch?

Tags: maven, http-unit

Today httpunit 1.7.2 was released on maven central.

There seem to be several "unofficial" patches available see:

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|httpunit

http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=project&project=httpunit

What is the difference between the 1.7.2 release and the two patches that Kohsuke created?
As a committer of httpunit I am willing to put these into httpunit if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not ask him? http://kohsuke.org/about/ has contact details.

The source-jars are available in the first link you provided. I have diffed them, the result is here

http://pastebin.com/Df90hCTY

Looks like a very minor change.

Comment: thanks for looking into this - there seems be a DocumentBuilderFactoryFilter in that release and it seems to be based on rev 984 of the official subversion repository at sourceforge. The 1.7.2 release is at rev 1118 at this time. Hopefully Kohsuke will get in touch and explain the reasons for his patch.